# OpenShift brmsworkshop not serving content

Tags: ruby, openshift, redhat

I am a new user on Openshift and trying to follow the steps to get the [bmrsworkshop](http://www.jboss.org/products/brms/get-started/#!project=brms) up and running.
Created an Openshift account ok.
Clicked the ["Click to install into Openshift"](https://github.com/eschabell/openshift-brms-workshop).
Does not respond when i try to open the app url.
Connecting to the back end of the app tells me it is trying to serve the directory.

"[Wed May 11 04:03:47 2016] [error] [client 127.3.121.129] Attempt to serve directory: /var/lib/openshift/5732e5037
628e1867c00005f/app-root/runtime/repo/public/"

There is nothing in this directory.

I also tried installing this from the rhc command line as

** NOW USING **

> **rhc app create brmsworkshop -t ruby-2.0 --from-code git://github.com/eschabell/openshift-brms-workshop.git**

Now i get

```
[Wed May 11 14:05:17 2016] [error] [client 127.2.236.129] Attempt to serve  directory: /var/lib/openshift/573373e52d52713baf000053/app-root/runtime/
repo/public/
[11/May/2016:14:05:17 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "-"
[Wed May 11 14:05:17 2016] [error] [client 127.2.236.129] Attempt to serve  directory: /var/lib/openshift/573373e52d52713baf000053/app-root/runtime/
repo/public/
- - - [11/May/2016:14:05:17 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "-"
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address   127.2.236.129:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[Wed May 11 14:07:01 2016] [error] [client 127.2.236.129] Attempt to serve directory: /var/lib/openshift/573373e52d52713baf000053/app-root/runtime /repo/public/
86.142.3.138 - - [11/May/2016:14:07:01 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 295 "-"  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/45.0"
```

Comment: I have submitted a Pull Request on that repo which will fix the issues that you are having, and have also emailed the author to ask that it be merged.

Comment: The github repo has now been updated via a pull request and should be working.

Comment: Repulled and get the errors above.